# How to find the position of the sampled element?

Tags: r, sample

I have defined a vector ,

```
x<-rep(10,times=10)
```

and ran the sample function ,

```
set.seed(42)
sample(x,1,replace=TRUE)
```

and of course, it will show a result of 10 but I want to know the position of this sampled element in the original vector x from where the element has been sampled out . How do we find it ? And furthermore , is there any way I can replace that sampled element with any other number ?

Comment: If you want to know the index of the sampled element, why not sample from the index set (and use the sampled index) rather than directly sample from the vector?

Comment: If you are only interested in the position and not in the element why don't you use `sample(1:length(x), 1)` ?

Answer (score 0):

A workaround would be naming the elements of `x`:

```
x <- rep(10,times=10)
names(x) <- letters[seq_along(x)]
which(names(x) == names(sample(x,1,replace=TRUE)))
```